# How can I deal with odd regression anlysis with control variables results from stargazer?

Tags: r, stargazer

I am struggling with the output of my regression analysis with control variables genrated using the stargazer package.
It looks like this:

```
Population     -0.00000*     -0.00000**         0.00000          0.00000    0.00000**   0.00000
               (0.00000)    (0.00000)   (0.00000)   (0.00000)   (0.00000)   (0.00000)
               t = -1.882   t = -2.362  t = 1.460   t = 0.593   t = 2.356   t = 0.832
               p = 0.065    p = 0.022   p = 0.149   p = 0.556   p = 0.022   p = 0.409
```

This certainly doesn't look right, but I don't know whats wrong. For all other independent/control variables I get perfectly normal results.

This is the code I used:

```
Controlmodel <- cbind(DataM$Age, DataM$GDP, DataM$Trade, DataM$Population, DataM$Population.Density, DataM$Corruption)
Modelwithcontrol <- lm(Environment ~ Election + Deliberation*Expression + Controlmodel, data=DataM)
stargazer::stargazer(Modelwithcontrol, type = "text", title = "Regression Analysis with Control Variables", style = "all",  out = 'Controlmodel.html')
```

As there is another control variable Population density in the model I checked for perfect collinearity, but the correlation coefficient is -0.055, which should not be a problem. I further tried excluding population denisty, but the same problem persists. I also tried shortening the data so I would have 300 instead of 30000, as I thought the problem could be that the numbers are too high. Non of this helped the results. I would be really happy and thankful if anyone had any idea, how to deal with this problem.

Comment: what doesn't look right about it? what are you expecting as far as results? is it the model that is wrong or the printing of the table

Comment: That all the estimated coefficients for population are 0.000. That can't be right. The model is ok, since the table shows "normal" results for all other variables. Do you have any ideas why the values are like that?

Comment: we can't really help without seeing your data. But sometimes when you see all 0's it could be a scaling problem of your variables. Try to rescale them (i.e divide by a 1000 or something like this) .

Comment: Thank you. It was a problem with the scaling. Dividing by 1000 fixed the problem.